# php - Codeigniter base_url() working but not working in other file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I think i've got something wrong, base_url is working fine in file index.php which i put it at directory views, but not working in file login.php where i put that file in same directory with file index.php..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!-- 
    Botany Template 
    http://www.templatemo.com/preview/templatemo_391_botany 
    -->
    **<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">**
    <link href="http://localhost/blabla/assets/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

see that code, 1st link is not worked, but 2nd link is worked.. Thanks for ur response..

Comment: Did you auto load url helper? In config/autoload.php

Comment: sure i did, but thanks for ur response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad is not load file login.php from controller, but directly to file..

Like this (wrong example):

```
<li><a href = "<?php echo base_url()."application/views/"; ?>login.php">Login</a></li>
```

Should be like this (correct example):

```
<li><a href = "<?php echo base_url()."index.php/*controller_name*/login"?>"></a></li>
```

But should create function in my controller like this:

```
public function login() {
$this->load->view("login.php");
}
```

This is solved my problem..

Comment: No need to write extension if loading php file, as: `public function login() {
$this->load->view("login");
}`. [Reference](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html#loading-a-view)